# Alguem pode me ajudar a escolher uma linha especifica da matriz ? (linguagem c/c++)

Tags: c, array, funções, matriz

Estou fazendo uma atividade e ela diz:

> (função – matriz e vetor) Elabore um programa que leia uma matriz 4x4 e crie um vetor de 4 elementos
> constituído dos elementos de uma linha da matriz escolhida pelo usuário
> meu problema é q não sei fazer ele printar exatamente a linha escolhida pelo usuário.

Meu programa acabou sendo só isso

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 
float matriz[4][4];
int d;
/* Entrada de dados na matriz */
printf(" Informe o valor de cada elemento -----\n");
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
 {
 printf(" \n matA(%d,%d) = ", i+1,j+1);
 scanf("%f", &matriz[i][j]);
 }
}
// escolha da linha
printf("escolha a linha desejada:");
scanf("%d",&d);

/* Escrita da matriz - saída formatada */
printf(" \n A matriz informada eh = \n");
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
 printf(" \n ");
 for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
 printf(" %4.1f ", matriz[i][j]);
}
}
```

Comment: Já pensou em não utilizar um loop para a linha (Iíndice `i`) e no lugar informar `d`? `for(int j=0; j<2; j++)  printf(" %4.1f ", matriz[d][j]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é bem simples, você pega linha do usuário e substitui na linha que o for percorre, assim voce vai percorrer somente pela linha que o usuário escolher.
Aqui ele está fazendo com uma matriz 2x2 que foi seu codigo de exemplo:

`````
int main() {
 
float matriz[4][4];
float vetor[4];
int d;
/* Entrada de dados na matriz */
printf(" Informe o valor de cada elemento -----\n");
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
 {
 printf(" \n matA(%d,%d) = ", i+1,j+1);
 scanf("%f", &matriz[i][j]);
 }
}
// escolha da linha
printf("escolha a linha desejada:");
scanf("%d",&d);


 
 printf(" \n ");
 for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
 printf(" %4.1f ", matriz[d][j]);
  vetor[j]=matriz[d][j];
 }
 //imprime vetor com os numeros da linha
 printf(" \n ");
 for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
 printf(" %4.1f",  vetor[j]);}

}````
`````